# Unable to add PriceBookEntry with APEX

Tags: apex, soql, pricebookentry

i want to add product price into **PricebookEntry** object with help of following APEX code:

```
PricebookEntry pBook = new PricebookEntry(UnitPrice = price,
                                          Product2 = productId
                );
insert pBook;
```

but when i try to save my code then it gave me following error:

> Invalid initial expression type for field Product2, expecting: Product2 
>       (or single row query result of that type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are receiving the error as you are trying to assign an ID to object placeholder.

Please try using `Product2Id = productId` instead of `Product2` in your code.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_PricebookEntry.htm)

Comment: thanks manjit my code is working now. thanks for you valuable comment